# Rails: Iterate dynamically over params hash to verify they exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a form with quite a bit of params being passed to the controller for processing.  The different 'sets' of params are named in a similar fashion:

```
setname1_paramname
setname1_paramname2
```

Now, I need to check one of these 'sets' to verify that all of the fields are submitted.  Right now, I'm doing this with a manual If Or style statement:

```
if setname1_paramname.blank? || setname1_paramname2.blank? || ...etc
  @object.errors.add_to_base("All setname1 fields are required.").
  render :action => 'new'
  return false
end
```

Is there way to programmatically loop over these params, and add them to the @object errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Do your params have a logic order, like series? In other term, are the next one like setname1_paramname3 and setname1_paramname4

Comment: No, unfortunately this is billing information, so it's more like billing_address, billing_state, etc

Comment: Doing that in your controller isn't really recommended. Keeping your business logic in your models **is** recommended.

Comment: Is it a paged form where you collect your data in more than one step?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it sounds like you have a ton of params and also seems like you need to be able to do checks on groups of params, maybe something like this would be useful? Basically, iterate over the params hash, and use regular expressions to target sets of params. Then, inside the loop, you can do any sort of validations:

```
params.each do |key, value| 
   # target groups using regular expressions
   if (key.to_s[/setname1.*/])
     # whatever logic you need for params that start with 'setname1'
     if param[key].blank?
       @object.errors.add_to_base("All setname1 fields are required.").
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Could you also use the rails 'starts_with?' string method to here?

Comment: Yep, I think that should work. I tested in irb by doing: `require 'active_support'` and then `require 'active_support/core_ext'` and then `"test123".starts_with?("test")` #=> true. And then: `"test123".starts_with?("false")` #=> false

Answer (score 6):

If the names are arbitrary and of your own choosing, you could make virtual attributes for them in your model and let Rails handle the presence checking.

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES = [:billing_address, :billing_state, :something_else]
  attr_accessor *VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES
  validates_presence_of *VIRTUAL_ATTRIBUTES
  …
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you wouldn't just store this information in a model, even if temporarily, and then just use rails validations for your information?

Comment: I would prefer to keep the logic in the model, but I have to verify the existence of these particular fields as a sort of "gateway" to further actions, without saving the model in question, until much further in the process.  Unfortunately, I'm working with inherited code, and can't change the process too much.

Comment: What kind of further actions? Is this something that you could save to the model and then if the model is saved have the further actions stalled as options in a second stage?  For example, save the model and redirect to the edit page; if the information checks out, have another form or set of actions listed from the edit page.

Comment: A model **won't save** if it fails validations.

Comment: That's kind of the point.  If everything needs to be validated before anything else can be done, only have the extra actions available in the edit screen. Let the model handle your validations and move the other actions as methods in the model itself that can be changed as 'updates.'  I guess my wording wasn't exactly true to the process, but I'm not sure the concept is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rusty but I assume that even if the value is blank the param will still be returned in the params hash as long as it is coming from a form element, yes? Could you just iterate through the params hash and keep a counter of how many values are not blank and then compare the length of the params hash to the counter. If the counter is short then you have blank parameters and can handle the error that way without having to hardcode checks for each individual parameter, yes?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a multi-step form as I suspect, you may find the [Railscast on Multistep Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) to be useful